# R error message: Timezone database not found - package tzdb

Tags: r

I got a new error message in R this morning when I tried to use the package "tzdb":
"Error: Timezone database not found at "C:/Users/jonand/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/tzdb/tzdata"

I am using R version 4.1.0 and version 0.1.2 of package tzdb.

Has anyone else come across this problem? Any ideas on how to fix it?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe this is related:  https://github.com/r-lib/tzdb/issues/10

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem. Thanks!

Comment: @Jonas8, have you solved it?

Comment: @AlitonOliveira Yes, I had to add a new R_LIBS_USER and that fixed it